# Remote debug WCF services running under a custom IIS account

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, iis-6, remote-debugging

I want to remote debug an WCF service. The application pool that hosts the WCF service runs under an custom account. The custom account is a domain account.

In the 'Attach to Process' window in Visual Studio 2012 I have checked 'Show all processes from all users' but it only shows WCF services that are hosted under a built-in IIS account (like NETWORK SERVICE, etc.).

How can I remotely debug this service?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've gone through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx, you may need to go through this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y5b4b4f.aspx

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing because it is not hosted in your application. You have to host the Remote WCF Service first. Add Service reference to add WCF to your app. Then right click WCFService.svc file to view WCF Service in browser to start the service. It will now be available to you and  you can Attach the process.